# Find and replace filenames recursivly ignoring folders

Tags: bash

I am trying to normalze filenames in a large group of files inside a folder and all sub folders. I have had limited sucess with this command

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/bob.smith/bob smith /' {} \;
```

This command works as expected except in the case where "bob.smith" exists in the name of a folder where a file with 'bob.smith' in its filename exists. In that case I receive the following :

```
Can't rename ./today.bob.smith.ok/1.bob.smith.344.txt ./today.bob smith.ok/1.bob.smith.344.txt: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/bob\.smith([^\/]+)$/bob smith $1/' {} \;
```

I modified the regex to identify those `bob.smith` who have not a `/` after them, and I used regex grouping (`(regex)` and `$1`) so I don't lose what is after `bob.smith`.

Note that since you wrote `s/bob.smith/` and not `s/bob.smith./` I assumed that you want the `.` after `bob.smith`. The result looks like this:

```
1.bob smith .344.txt
```

Note also the `bob\.smith` instead of `bob.smith`. In regex `.` means "any char".

Comment: This seems to work thank you. It does brings up a follow up - would there be a way to add a wild card so it will normalize all the filenames in one pass? bob.smith, bob_smith, bobsmith => bob smith ?

Previously I have just executed multiple rename commands to cover the different possibilities.

Comment: @jademonke33 Yes, you could use `s/bob.?smith([^\/]+)$/bob smith $1/`. This will match every time you have the word `bob` followed by the word `smith` and there is max one char between them. Have you already seen [someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?